# CNN - multidimensional matrix as input or parallel input for parallel CNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, cnn, convolution, functional-api

I want to run CNN on 20 channels of images.
One way is to run on a 20-channel multidimensional matrix (like RGB ). Another way is to run 20 CNN on one channel at a time ( R apart from G separately from B as separate inputs ) and finally connect by concatenate

What is more appropriate to do and is there a difference in the results?